# cannot import Random after importing xlsxwriter

Tags: python, module

I'm learning python modules right now and I'm trying to use xlsxwriter module, I used sample code online but it seems like there is an import error

```
import xlrd
from optparse import OptionParser                                                            

import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello world')

workbook.close()


loc = ("~/desktop/dictionary.xlsx")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('random.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 40)

temp = random.sample(random(100),100)


for x in temp:
    a = sheet.cell_value(x, 0) 
    b = sheet.cell_value(x, 1)
    c = sheet.cell_value(x, 2)
    worksheet.write(a,b,c)

workbook.save("~/desktop/random.xlsx")
workbook.close
```

However, there is an error called:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mingtaosun/Desktop/hi.py", line 4, in <module>
    import xlsxwriter
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .workbook import Workbook
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .worksheet import Worksheet
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py", line 14, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
```

What should I do

Comment: When I run your code I get a different exception: `NameError: name 'random' is not defined`. It looks like you aren't importing  "random", using a non-existent function called `random()` and also not using `random.sample()` correctly. There isn't a `workbook.save()` method either. You should fix these issues first. They don't relate to XlsxWriter.